# advanced custom fields Checkbox

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox

I am using advanced custom fields Checkbox feature in wordpress.

I have created a `<ul>` with four `<li>`

```
<ul class="post-icons">
  <li class="microphone" title="Alt text"></li>
  <li class="video" title="Alt text"></li>
  <li class="text" title="Alt text"></li>
  <li class="image" title="Alt text"></li>
</ul>
```

And i have created four Checkboxes in advanced custom fields. If I use this PHP in the `class="(here)"`.

```
<?php echo implode(' ', get_field('field_name')); ?>
```

It will print the value of the Checkboxes on to the class"" but it will print all four Checkboxes values that i have created. I only would like to print the right one on the right place.

The best way would to use `.active` class but advanced custom fields doesn't allow multiple Checkboxes with the same value. I mean that if you Check a Checkbox on **Image** and **text** it would print `.active` or something wise on

```
<li class="image" title="Alt text"></li> and 
<li class="text" title="Alt text"></li> 

Like = <li class="image active" title="Alt text"></li> and <li class="text active" title="Alt text"></li>
```

I have four Checkboxes

- Video
- Text
- Sound
- Image

And four `<li>`

```
 - <li class="video"></li>
 - <li class="text"></li>
 - <li class="microphone"></li>
 - <li class="image"></li>
```

microphone = Sound

I would like to print `.active` on the right `<li>` `class""` item. When the corresponding Checkbox is checked

I will link to the Documentation for advanced custom fields Checkbox I didn't understand a lot of how to create something what I would need for my project.

[Documentation](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/field-types/checkbox/)

Comment: I'm not quite understanding... What are the choices of the checkbox (in ACF config)? Why would you need them with the same value in the config? Why are you imploding the field?

Comment: Hi brasofilo, I would like to use the Checkboxes for easily adding a class name for my Post icons that they would show on the page. My checkbox choices are Sound, Video, Text, Image. If I check Text and image it would look like this  [link](http://alturl.com/soomx) See the two white icons next to post title. I hope that this clarified a little what I'm doing.

Comment: Please, [edit] your Question and show us how the Html should render based on the field value.

Comment: brasofilo I modified my question now hopefully it is better now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not really clear from the Question what Fields exist.

In the case of a Checkbox field (check [PHP ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)):

```
// If checked, the string is 'active', otherwise empty
$image = ( get_field( 'image_field' ) ) ? 'active' : '';
$video = ( get_field( 'video_field' ) ) ? 'active' : ''; 

<li class="image <?php echo $image; ?>" title="Alt text"></li> 
<li class="video <?php echo $video; ?>" title="Alt text"></li>
```

---

But, better yet is a [Select field](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/field-types/select/) allowing multiple selections (check [PHP in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)):
[image: acf select multiple]

```
$get_field = get_field( 'field_name' ); 
$image = in_array( 'image', $get_field) ? 'active' : '';
$video = in_array( 'video', $get_field) ? 'active' : '';

<li class="image <?php echo $image; ?>" title="Alt text"></li> 
<li class="video <?php echo $video; ?>" title="Alt text"></li>
```

Comment: Hi brasofilo, Your example is working perfectly! Thanks for that. It Works in Select field and in checkbox field! It's Wonderful and works perfectly! : )